# Time dilation as an effect of energy density

Tags: general-relativity, stress-energy-momentum-tensor, time-dilation

Has any relation been observed or postulated to exist between the energy-density (or the surrounding space) of an object and time dilation?

i.e. Higher energy density==>Slower rate of time?

Comment: Energy density effects time dilation, because greater energy density $\to$ greater mass in the same area of the object $\to$ greater time dilation.

Comment: so then why can't general and special relativity be united using energy-density? Are they not different descriptions of energy density?

Comment: Because I'm talking about *gravitational* time dilation, not time dilation from traveling fast. Speed and mass can cause time dilation, but they are not the same.

Comment: Why would one have to unite special and general relativity when special relativity is anyway a special case of general relativity?

Comment: HDE 226868, Space-time "bends" or "gravitates" toward objects with mass right? So, if the surrounding space is the frame of reference for determining the speed of the object through space, then space is passing over an object more quickly when the object is in a gravity well. so space wouldn't know the difference between passing over an object more quickly and the object passing through it more quickly. This makes special and general relativity the same thing. right?

Comment: @lea There is no absolute frame of reference, so the second-to-last sentence is correct. I don't see how that makes SR and GR the same thing, though.

Comment: SR and GR would be the same thing because, in both cases the time dilation would be caused by the objects rate of motion through space. Whether its an effect of space moving with a higher energy density as it gets deeper into the gravity well or what have you... It's the same effect from the same cause. The time dilation is a function of the energy density of an object. The density increases with rate of motion and when descending into a gravity well. i am wondering if the two could be explained with one equation.

Comment: for some reason im reminded of fractile drawings. It seems like increased energy density is like zooming in on a fractile. if you measure the california coast on a small enough scale then the distance becomes infinite! could higher energy density force photons to "travel" greater "distances"?

Answer (score 2):

The formula for [gravitational time dilation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_time_dilation)<sup>1</sup> is
$$\frac{t_0}{t_f}=\sqrt{1-\frac{2GM}{rc^2}}$$
For a sphere,
$$M=V \rho = \frac{4}{3} \pi r^3 \rho$$
So
$$\frac{t_0}{t_f}=\sqrt{1-\frac{8G \pi r^2 \rho}{3c^2}}$$
So the greater the density, the greater the time dilation.

> Has any relation been observed or postulated to exist between the energy-density (or the surrounding space) of an object and time dilation?

Yes. In every single case, in fact - not just the spherically symmetric static cases, as I gave above.

---

<sup>1</sup> Around a static, spherically symmetrical object.

Comment: so why can't general and special relativity be unified using energy density?

Comment: @lea - Симон Тыран hit the nail on the head. Special relativity is just a special case of general relativity. No unification necessary.

Comment: SR and GR would be the same thing because, in both cases the time dilation would be caused by the objects rate of motion through space. Whether its an effect of space moving with a higher energy density as it gets deeper into the gravity well or what have you... It's the same effect from the same cause. The time dilation is a function of the energy density of an object. The density increases with rate of motion and when descending into a gravity well. i am wondering if the two could be explained with one equation. –  lea 52 mins ago

Comment: for some reason im reminded of fractile drawings. It seems like increased energy density is like zooming in on a fractile. if you measure the california coast on a small enough scale then the distance becomes infinite! could higher energy density force photons to "travel" greater "distances"?

Comment: @lea *SR and GR would be the same thing because, in both cases the time dilation would be caused by the objects rate of motion through space.* I don't understand; mass would still cause gravitational time dilation. *The density increases with rate of motion and when descending into a gravity well.* No, not if density is uniform. The relevant thing here is the density of the object doing the dilating, not the affected object.

Comment: what im trying to bring to fruition is the idea that gravitational waves move at the speed of light right? gravitational time dilation is being caused by the difference in energy density of those "waves" which increases the closer you are to a gravity well. (theoretically)

Comment: @lea Perhaps, but those are *completely different things*. In one case, mass/energy is causing dilation; in the other, speed is causing dilation. I'm also not sure how gravitational waves could cause time dilation.

Comment: not gravitational waves but gravity in general. If an objects mass increases with kinetic energy (motion) than the objects kinetic energy is also increasing with mass.  in gravity wells, space (or whatever it is that is affected by gravity) is the thing moving, always at the speed of light toward the nearest body of mass, but with higher energy density as you get closer (causing relative time dilation). In special relativity, space is still moving toward the nearest bodies of mass with whatever energy density but the object is also moving.(causing relative time dilation)

Answer (score 1):

In both GR and SR, the passage of time is dependent upon the energy state - in the special theory, the passage of time logged by two clocks in relative motion depends upon the kinetic energy $(v^2/c^2)$ difference whereas in the general theory, the passage of time depends upon the gravitational potential $(2GM/rc^2)$.  This in turn, is simply the escape velocity (the kinetic energy required to extricate a mass from the gravitational well).  So the bottom line is, time dilation in both SR and GR can be expressed by the same factors